# Upload file with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload

I'm trying to do a simple file upload, but it's giving an error, below is how I did it.

Form:

```
<div class="container">
   <div th:replace="~{base :: titulo('Disparar Holerites')}"></div>
    <div class="card mt-3">
      <form class="card-body needs-validation" action="/holerite/uploadHoleritesFile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        <div>
            <label for="arquivoContabilidade" class="form-label">Arquivo Recebido da Contabilidade</label>
            <div class="input-group has-validation mb-4">
                <input accept=".pdf"  type="file" class="form-control" id="arquivoContabilidade" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>

            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enviar</button>
      </form>
  </div>
```

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "uploadHoleritesFile")
public String uploadHoleritesFile(@RequestParam("arquivoContabilidade") MultipartFile arquivoContabilidade, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
    logger.info("Entramos aqui");
    logger.info("Recebido o arquivo: "+!arquivoContabilidade.isEmpty());
    if(arquivoContabilidade.isEmpty()){
        return "redirect:holerites/passo1";
    }
    try{
        byte[] bytes = arquivoContabilidade.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(COTABILIDADE_FOLDER + arquivoContabilidade.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(path, bytes);


    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "holerites/passo2";


}
```

Error:

2022-02-04 18:36:41.048 DEBUG 17136 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={multipart}
2022-02-04 18:36:41.057 DEBUG 17136 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2022-02-04 18:36:41.077 DEBUG 17136 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2022-02-04 18:36:41.081 DEBUG 17136 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 403

Answer (score 0):

You should add an attribute **`name="arquivoContabilidade"`** to your input field in your html. Thymeleaf uses the **`name`** attribute when it maps it to a multipart file.

Example:

```
<input accept=".pdf" name="arquivoContabilidade" type="file" class="form-control" id="arquivoContabilidade" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" required>
```

Also, I'm assuming that you controller has the annotation `@RequestMapping("/holerite")`.

If it doesn't you will also have to change

```
@PostMapping(value = "uploadHoleritesFile")
```

to

```
@PostMapping(value = "/holerite/uploadHoleritesFile")
```

because your form has
`<form action="/holerite/uploadHoleritesFile" method="POST"...>`

Comment: I add put the attribute here and not work yet, in my Controller i use this annotation too @RequestMapping("holerite")
public class HoleriteController {